# PHP to download file not working with spaces

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script to check if a file exists or not. If the file exists, start download of file.

```php
$get_file = $_GET['file'];
$file_raw = '/var/www/data.xxxx.com/html/' . $get_file;
$file = str_replace(' ', '\\ ', $file_raw);;

if (!file_exists($file)) { // file does not exist
    die('file not found - ' . $file);
} else {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $fileName = basename($file);
        $fileSize = filesize($file);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: " . $fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);

        // Output file.
        passthru("cat $file");
        exit();
    } else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
}
```

The issue I am encountering is if the $_GET request contains a space, I get a file not found. This is why I implemented the str_replace but this also does not help.

Comment: You only need to escape spaces in the shell, and then only if you don't quote the argument. Space has no special meaning in filenames in programs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the spaces when you call `file_exists()`. So use

```
if (!file_exists($file_raw))
```

When you use the shell, such as with `passthru()`, you should use `escapeshellarg()` to escape any special characters in the argument. Don't try to do it yourself with `str_replace()`, since there are other special characters beside spaces.

```
$safe_file = escapeshellarg($file_raw);
passthru("cat $safe_file");
```

However, it's not necessary to use `passthru()` in the first place. PHP has a function `readfile()` that copies a file to the output. So just use

```
readfile($file_raw);
```